# Rotate x-axis text when using coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter-plot with many values on a polar axis  - *coord_polar()*. The resulting graph has crowded text because the text is always aligned with the bottom of the page.

Is it possible to place the text so that it is printed radially along the polar x-axis?

---

**Edited to provide an example:**

```
qplot(data=presidential, name,end) + coord_polar()
```

In the presidential case I would like to see the presidential names angled to align with the axis/spoke they are on. Below is an example of the graph I am working on where the x axis is categorical and the y-axis is a continuous variable (similar to the example).

[image]

Comment: can you provide reproducible example?

Comment: Given that `theme_text(angle = )` only supports one value the way to go is get rid of the axis labels and use geom_text calculating the angles yourself. Or maybe modifing the source to accept multiple angles. But I leave that to someone more knowledgeable in ggplot2 guts.

Comment: `qplot(data=presidential, name,end) + coord_polar() + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=360/ 8 * seq_along(presidential$name)))` gives warnings, but still uses multiple angles.

Comment: thanks baptiste. I like your idea but the rotations on the bottom half of the graph (axes included) are off. But I like where you are going . Do you think it would be possible to add a fuction inside of the theme_text(). Worth a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a not elegant example of the coordinate:

```
CoordPolar2 <- proto(CoordPolar, {
  objname <- "polar2"
  guide_foreground <- function(., details, theme) {
    theta <- .$theta_rescale(details$theta.major, details)
    labels <- details$theta.labels

    # Combine the two ends of the scale if they are close
    theta <- theta[!is.na(theta)]
    ends_apart <- (theta[length(theta)] - theta[1]) %% (2*pi)
    if (ends_apart < 0.05) {
      n <- length(labels)
      if (is.expression(labels)) {
        combined <- substitute(paste(a, "/", b), 
          list(a = labels[[1]], b = labels[[n]]))
      } else {
        combined <- paste(labels[1], labels[n], sep="/")
      }
      labels[[n]] <- combined
      labels <- labels[-1]
      theta <- theta[-1]
    }

    grobTree(
      if (length(labels) > 0) {
        lab <- theme_render(
          theme, "axis.text.x", 
          labels, 0.45 * sin(theta) + 0.5, 0.45 * cos(theta) + 0.5,
          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5,
          default.units="native"
        )
        lab$rot <- (pi/2 - theta) / pi * 180
        lab
      },
      theme_render(theme, "panel.border")
    )
  }
})

coord_polar2 <- CoordPolar2$build_accessor()

p <- qplot(data=presidential, name,end) + coord_polar2()
print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I understand this is an old topic, but I found a better solution for this problem, inspired from baptise's comment:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=someId, y=someValue)) +
  geom_point() + 
  coord_polar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle= -90 - 360 / length(unique(data$someId)) * seq_along(data$someId)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer by Yoplait helps a lot, but still does not solve the issue of having to read upside down in half of the graph. An extention of the idea that this poster proposes is as follows.

First prepare the angle vector, making sure we split the graph in two:

```
sequence_length = length(unique(data$someId))
first_sequence = c(1:(sequence_length%/%2)) 
second_sequence = c((sequence_length%/%2+1):sequence_length) 
first_angles = c(90 - 180/length(first_sequence) * first_sequence)
second_angles = c(-90 - 180/length(second_sequence) * second_sequence)
```

And now we can append the angle vectors to make the actual graph:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=someId, y=someValue)) +
  geom_point() + 
  coord_polar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle= c(first_angles,second_angles)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: now part of ggplot2 3.5.0+

The development version of ggplot2 just added a new `coord_radial()` and `guide_axis_theta()` that makes this problem easier by just setting  the axis angle.

```r
library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2") # Development version
#> [1] '3.4.4.9000'

p <- ggplot(presidential, aes(name, end)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_radial()

p + guides(theta = guide_axis_theta(angle = 90))
```

[image]

The same strategy also works for setting the text angle as a tangent to the circle.

```r
p + guides(theta = guide_axis_theta(angle = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your reprex is a somewhat particularly difficult case, what with the double Bushs and Dates on the x-axis and all, so I couldn't be bothered to make it work for that, **but:** check out [geomtextpath](https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/)'s [`geom_textvline`](https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/reference/geom_textabline.html), it works like `geom_vline` but with text.